# convert an int to string ascii value

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello I have an int varible in python and would like to get the value of the integer in a string.
For example if I have this variable
var:int = 0
How to put the value '\0' in a str variable?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

U can convert most variable types in python by using  a simple function:
        string_variable= str(int)

Hope this helps

Comment: I will get the character '0' and not '\0'

Comment: Why do you want '\0'? What would you want if the int is 1 or 2 for example?

Comment: where is the expectation that it should have a leading backslash? should that backslash just be applied to every int regardless of its value?

Comment: I want '\0' value if the int is 0 and '\x01' if the value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have variable var1m that has integer value, to convert it into a string you just need to pass str()

```
var1 = 1
var2 = '\\' + str(var1)
print(var2)
print(type(var2))
```

this will output

```
\1
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm stil not entirely sure what you want but you can try `bytes`:

```
>>> bytes([0])
b'\x00'
>>> bytes([1])
b'\x01'
>>> bytes([0, 1])
b'\x00\x01'
```

This will create a byte object from a list of bytes, meaning numbers between 0 and 255. To get a string use `str(bytes(...))`.